# How to make an image disappear after clicking it?

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift5

I want to make a small image.png disappears after clicking it. 
I'm a newborn of swift so I'm using single view on Playground for my experiments. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code while creating your_imageView

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
your_imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
your_imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView

    tappedImage.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But why it gives me "Use of local variable 'imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)' before its declaration"?

Comment: Move the definition of your imageTapped() function above the code that creates the gesture recognizer. That should fix your "Use of local variable 'imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)' before its declaration" problem.